# What does it mean to say that "unions are currently performed based on location, not on schema"?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am currently reading **Spark: The Definitive Guide**. It's very well-written.

However, I am currently reading about the union operation for Dataframes and have run across a statement I do not understand.

> Unions are currently performed based on location, not on the schema. This means that columns will not automatically line up the way you think they might.

Can anyone explain what this statement means? It is given it's own text-box with the heading "WARNING" in all-caps, so this sounds important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that the union of two tables is based on the position and order of the table columns and not on the names of the columns.

Imagine you have two tables with the following columns.

Table1:

```
colA | colB | colC
-----+------+------
val1a| val1b| val1c
```

Table2:

```
colA | colC | colB
-----+------+------
val2a| val2c| val2b
```

The union of those two tables would end up like this:

```
colA | colB | colC
-----+------+------
val1a| val1b| val1c
val2a| val2c| val2b
```

Usually, as it is also stated in the book, to union two DataFrames it has to be ensured that they have the same schema and number of columns. Otherwise, the union will fail. My example `Table1` and `Table2` fulfill these two requirements, however, the "column location" ist not the same.

Comment: Note that it exists a "unionByName" operation which prevents such unexpected behaviour.